# Using a index value to define a header row

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am using:

```
# find first row where transaction appears

fintran = df[df['Unnamed: 0'].astype(str).str.contains('Transaction')]
print (fintran.index)
```

Which correctly returns the row index which in this case is row 18 = Int64Index([18], dtype='int64')

I can manually define the column headers and swap them around etc using:

```
# Assign row as column headers
header_row = 18
df.columns = df.iloc[header_row]
print(df)

# Convert row to column header using DataFrame.iloc[]
df.columns = df.iloc[18]
print(df)
```

My QUESTION is how to use the index value I first found as the value of the row? For example if the number of rows above the row containing transaction vary

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#mask for get row
m = df['Unnamed: 0'].astype(str).str.contains('Transaction')
#assign columns names
df.columns = df[m].iloc[0]
#if always match condition one row
#df.columns = df[m].squeeze()

#remove row by mask
df = df[~m]
```